# this.props.history.push is undefined in React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history, react-props

I want to perform history.push
but it is not working.
i have used withRouter , History etc.
can anyone help me to resolve it

```
register=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    }

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './component/login/login'
import Header from './component/header/header'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const his=createBrowserHistory()

class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return (
  <Router history={his} >
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/register" component={Login} exact/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

}
}

export default App;

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Where does this method live?

Comment: register function is used in another component as code is long i cannot mention it

Comment: Can you show the code where you have defined the routes?

Comment: @Pradeep Full code or a sandbox atleast?